# Data Access in Master DetailView with multiple Xib for Detail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiview

I have a data like userName,DOB,Registation No: And Address , I created 10 XIB file for 
for detail View which is open When clicking on the MasterView table Cell, in the 2nd XIB file of detail view i have a information of user when i select the user in second Xib of the How i can access that data in my 3rd to 10th XIB ?? i dont know the data delegation in iphone bcoz m new in iphone developing ??

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding on your project:

1. You start with the MasterViewController (First controller)
2. After selecting or clicking a row/cell, another controller loads which contains 
   a list of users? (I'm not so sure) wherein each user has information (containing userName, DOB, etc.). So, this means that in this controller - you assign those information to the the respective users. (Second controller)
3. Then when you select a particular user, another controller loads where you want to use the data from this controller - might be, this is where you want to display those information assigned from the second controller. (Third controller)

So, if we are on the same page, here's what you're going to do:

(Let's say, you're done with the MainView (FirstController) and you're already in the SecondViewController)

For starters, you can do something like this:

1. Create a global variable in the ThirdViewController, which will hold the information being passed by the SecondViewController. In this case,

/////////~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/////////
/////////~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ThirdViewController.h~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/////////
/////////~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/////////

```
@interface ThirdViewController:UIViewController{
    NSDictionary *dictInformation;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dictInformation;
@end

@implementation ThirdViewController
@synthesize dictInformation;

...
   // some codes here...
   // you can use the information passed from the SecondViewController
...

- (void)dealloc{
     [dictInformation release], dictInformation = nil;
     [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

/////////~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/////////
/////////~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~SecondViewController.h~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/////////
/////////~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/////////

```
@implementation SecondViewController

    // This is the assignment of data. You can put this in viewDidload
    // user 1
     NSMutableDictionary *aUser1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [aUser1 setObject:@"josh123" forKey:@"userName"];
    [aUser1 setObject:@"01-01-1987" forKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
    [aUser1 setObject:@"12345678" forKey:@"regNumber"];
    [aUser1 setObject:@"24-H 1st St. New York" forKey:@"address"];
    // user 2
    NSMutableDictionary *aUser2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [aUser2 setObject:@"josh321" forKey:@"userName"];
    [aUser2 setObject:@"01-02-1988" forKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
    [aUser2 setObject:@"87654321" forKey:@"regNumber"];
    [aUser2 setObject:@"42-H 1st St. New York" forKey:@"address"];

   // I assigned all users to an array
    NSArray *arrayOfUsers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:aUser1, aUser2, nil];
    [aUser1 release];
    [aUser2 release];

   // Pass the value of arrayOfUsers somewhere to that it can be accessed
   // or it can be a 

   /* At this point, the following has values:
   arrayOfUsers[0] = aUser1 -> {'josh123', '01-01-1987', '12345678', '24-H 1st St. New York'}
   arrayOfUsers[1] = aUser2 -> {'josh321', '01-02-1988', '87654321', '42-H 1st St. New York'}
   */

    // You can actually add the following codes anywhere, depending on your implementation. It can be when you clicked a cell or a button, etc.

      ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    // assign a dictionary value to dictInformation which is found in ThirdViewController
    // If you are using UITableView, then, this should be done when you are selecting a cell in the tableView and the value of the index should be indexPath.row
      [thirdViewController setDictInformation:[arrayOfUsers objectAtIndex:0]]; 
      // This pushes to the ThirdViewController
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];
      [thirdViewController release];

      ...
@end
```

**Note**: This is only a fragment of codes...I just want to give you an idea on how to do it. Hope this helps, though. Good luck! :)